# How to calculate the index between two complex lattices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\Lambda$,$\Lambda'$ be two complex lattices and $m\neq 0\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $m\Lambda\subset\Lambda'$. Suppose $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are the basis of $\Lambda$, $\omega'_1,\omega'_2$ are the basis of $\Lambda'$. So we have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}m\omega_1\\m\omega_2\end{bmatrix}=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}\omega_1'\\\omega'_2\end{bmatrix}\text{ for some }\alpha\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})
$$

Then it is said that $[\Lambda',m\Lambda]=\det\alpha$.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is rather $|\det\alpha|$.
The parallelogram spanned by $a\choose c$ and $b\choose d$ happens to have exactly area $|ad-bc|$, and so it contains $|ad-bc|$ lattice points.

Comment: I'm still confused. $\Lambda',m\Lambda$ are regarded as two groups here, how does the index involve $|\det\alpha|$?. Can you show me more detail?