# Application of the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, quotient-spaces

I've been trying to figure out the correct way to do this and I'm not sure I've got it quite right.

$\mathbb{Z}^4/S$ where $S = \{(4, 12,20,8),(6,30,18,12),(4,16,16,8),(8,40,24,16) \}$

So, $M_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
     6       & 30 & 18 & 12 \\
    4       & 12 & 20 &  8 \\ 
  4       & 16 & 16 & 8 \\
    8       & 40 & 24 & 16
\end{bmatrix}$, since $\gcd(4,6,4,8)=2$ then $$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
     2       & 18 & -2 & 4 \\
    0       & -24 & 24 &  0 \\ 
  0       & -20 & 20 & 0 \\
    0       & -32 & 32 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
     2       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -24 & 24 &  0 \\ 
  0       & -20 & 20 & 0 \\
    0       & -32 & 32 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now $\gcd(-24,-20,-32)=4$, $M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
     2       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & -4 & 4 &  0 \\ 
  0       & -20 & 20 & 0 \\
    0       & -32 & 32 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
     2       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 4 & 0 &  0 \\ 
  0       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then the rank of $\mathbb{Z}^4/S$ is 2 and $\mathbb{Z}^4 / S \simeq \mathbb{Z}^2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4 $.

I haven't been able to explicitly find the isomorphism between the two, which is one of the reasons I'm not sure if it's right. Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like you were putting the matrix in the Smith normal form, which is, indeed, a very good way of finding the structure of the quotient group. One way of finding an actual isomorphism need you to keep track of the row/column operatiions that you performed while getting there. I tried to explain the process [in this old answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/46437/11619). I'm not sure I did a good job there.